Displaying validation message on razor page when using viewbag
I have the following code - model classes:
public partial class EmployeeInfo
{
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Job Title is required.")]
    [DisplayName("Job Title")]
    public virtual JobTitleLookup JobTitleLookup { get; set; }
}

public class JobTitleLookup
{
     public int JobTitleLookupId { get; set; }
     
     public string Title { get; set; } = null!;

     public virtual List<EmployeeInfo> EmployeeInfos { get; } = new List<EmployeeInfo>();
 }
 

This is the controller:
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
 {
     jobTitle = await _Reassign.GetJobTitle();
     ViewData["Jobs"] = new SelectList(jobTitle, "JobTitleLookupId", "Title");
 }

This is inside the service
public async Task<List<JobTitleLookup>> GetJobTitle()
{
     return await _ackContext.JobTitleLookup
                             .OrderBy(c => c.Title).ToListAsync();
}
 

This is the view:
<div class="col-md-4">
        <label asp-for="JobTitleLookup" class="control-label" style="font-weight:bold;"></label>
        <select asp-for="JobTitleLookup" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Jobs">

            <option value="0">--Please select--</option>
    </select>
       
        <span asp-validation-for="JobTitleLookup" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

When I run the code, I don't see the error message that Job Title is required. However, I see the error message saying "First name is required". I also tried to put the validation message inside the controller like this:
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(EmployeeInfo info)
{
    if (info.JobTitleLookupId ==0)
    {
        var validationMessage = "Job Title is required";
        this.ModelState.AddModelError("JobTitleLookupId", validationMessage);
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    }

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}

Still, I don't see the validation message saying Job title is required.
Any help will be highly appreciated.


In your view, you are not sending the selected value for "JobTitleLookupId" to the controller action. You should apply "JobTitleLookupId" instead of "JobTitleLookup" in the asp-for tag.

<div class="col-md-4">
    <label asp-for="JobTitleLookupId" class="control-label" style="font-weight:bold;"></label>
    <select asp-for="JobTitleLookupId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Jobs">

        <option value="0">--Please select--</option>
    </select>

    <span asp-validation-for="JobTitleLookupId" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>


In your Controller action, you should not use RedirectToAction as this will result the whole view to refresh (load the "Index" with GET action and result the ModelState being resetted). Instead, return with View and provide the info as model.

Besides, you should to implement a method for initialize the ViewBag/ViewData when navigate to the Index action (for GET and POST method).
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    await InitializeIndexData();

    ...
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(EmployeeInfo info)
{

    await InitializeIndexData();
    ...

    return View(info);
}

private async Task InitializeIndexData()
{
    List<JobTitleLookup> jobTitle = await GetJobTitle();
    ViewData["Jobs"] = new SelectList(jobTitle, "JobTitleLookupId", "Title");
}

